# toast mesage not shown on screen when network or server not available

Tags: android, android-activity

I need to show toast message when the server is not responding
when I press the login button, some parameters are passed  to AgAppMenu screen which  use url    connection to server and get xml response in AgAppHelperMethods screen. The
probelm is when  the server is busy or the network is not avaibale, I can't show toast message on catch block although it shows the log message.

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.Intent ;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class LoginScreen extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

EditText mobile;
EditText pin;
Button btnLogin;
Button btnClear;

public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
    super.onCreate(icicle);
    setContentView(R.layout.agapplogin);

    TextView lblMobileNo = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.lblMobileNo);
    lblMobileNo.setTextColor(getResources()
            .getColor(R.color.text_color_red));

    mobile = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtMobileNo);

    TextView lblPinNo = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.lblPinNo);
    lblPinNo.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.text_color_red));

    pin = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtPinNo);

    btnLogin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnLogin);
    btnClear = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnClear);

    btnLogin.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {
            postLoginData();

        }
    });

    btnClear.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v)

        {
            cleartext();
        }

    });

    /*
     * 
     * btnClear.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() { public void
     * onClick(View arg0) {
     * 
     * } });
     */

}

public void postLoginData()

{

    if (pin.getTextSize() == 0 || mobile.getTextSize() == 0) {

        AlertDialog.Builder altDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        altDialog.setMessage("Please Enter Complete Information!");

    } else {
        Intent i = new Intent(this.getApplicationContext(),  AgAppMenu.class);          
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putString("mno", mobile.getText().toString());
        bundle.putString("pinno", pin.getText().toString());
        i.putExtras(bundle);
        startActivity(i);
    }
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

}

public void cleartext() {

    {
        pin.setText("");
        mobile.setText("");
    }

}

}


  import android.app.Activity;
  import android.content.Intent;
  import android.os.Bundle;
  import android.view.View;
  import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
  import android.widget.Button;
  import android.widget.TextView;
  import android.widget.Toast;

 public class AgAppMenu extends Activity {

String mno, pinno;

private String[][] xmlRespone;


Button btnMiniStatement;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.agappmenu);

    mno = getIntent().getExtras().getString("mno");
    pinno = getIntent().getExtras().getString("pinno");

    setTitle("Welcome to the Ag App Menu");

    AgAppHelperMethods agapp =new AgAppHelperMethods();


//  xmlRespone =   AgAppHelperMethods.AgAppXMLParser("AG_IT_App/AgMainServlet?messageType=LOG&pin=" + pinno + "&mobile=" + mno + "&source=" + mno   + "&channel=INTERNET");
    xmlRespone = agapp.AgAppXMLParser("AG_IT_App/AgMainServlet?messageType=LOG&pin="    + pinno + "&mobile=" + mno + "&source=" + mno   + "&channel=INTERNET");







 import java.net.URL;

  import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
  import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;

  import org.w3c.dom.Document;
  import org.w3c.dom.Node;
  import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;
  import org.xml.sax.InputSource;

  import android.app.Activity;
  import android.os.Bundle;
  import android.util.Log;
  import android.widget.Toast;
  import android.view.View;
  import android.view.View.OnKeyListener;

  public class AgAppHelperMethods extends Activity {

private static final String LOG_TAG = null;

private static AgAppHelperMethods instance = null;

public static String varMobileNo;
public static String varPinNo;

String[][] xmlRespone = null;

boolean flag = true;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.agapphelpermethods);

}

protected AgAppHelperMethods() {

}

public static AgAppHelperMethods getInstance() {
    if (instance == null) {
        instance = new AgAppHelperMethods();
    }
    return instance;
}

public static String getUrl() {

    String url = "https://demo.accessgroup.mobi/";

    return url;

}

public String[][] AgAppXMLParser(String parUrl) {

    String _node, _element;
    String[][] xmlRespone = null;
    try {

        String url = AgAppHelperMethods.getUrl() + parUrl;
        URL finalUrl = new URL(url);

        DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document doc = db.parse(new InputSource(finalUrl.openStream()));
        doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();

        NodeList list = doc.getElementsByTagName("*");
        _node = new String();
        _element = new String();
        xmlRespone = new String[list.getLength()][2];

        // this "for" loop is used to parse through the
        // XML document and extract all elements and their
        // value, so they can be displayed on the device

        for (int i = 0; i < list.getLength(); i++) {
            Node value = list.item(i).getChildNodes().item(0);
            _node = list.item(i).getNodeName();
            _element = value.getNodeValue();
            xmlRespone[i][0] = _node;
            xmlRespone[i][1] = _element;

        }// end for
        throw new ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException();
    }// end try
    // will catch any exception thrown by the XML parser

    catch (Exception e) {
        Toast.makeText(AgAppHelperMethods.this,
                "error  server not responding " + e.getMessage(),
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Log.e(LOG_TAG, "CONNECTION ERROR  FUNDAMO SERVER NOT RESPONDING", e);

    }

    // Log.e(LOG_TAG, "CONNECTION ERROR  FUNDAMO SERVER NOT RESPONDING", e);

    return xmlRespone;

}
    `
```

Comment: Toast.makeText(AgAppHelperMethods.this instead of this use getApplicationContext().

Comment: Are you getting CONNECTION ERROR  FUNDAMO SERVER NOT RESPONDING message in LOgcat

Comment: Slightly off topic but why are you setting the text colour to red in code? While there is nothing syntactically wrong with this, is it not a better separation of concerns to have the layout XML handle the presentation as much as possible and the code execute the business logic. This would also reduce the amount of code to sift through while debugging.

Comment: You also should look at doing this asynchronously, as I cannot see evidence of this from your code.

Answer (score 0):

`AgAppHelperMethods` isn't really an `Activity`. You've derived this class from `Activity`, but then you've created Singleton management methods (`getInstance()`) and you are instantiating it yourself. This is bad. Don't do this.

Normally Android controls the instantiation of activities. You don't ever create one yourself (with `new`).

It looks to me like `AgAppHelperMethods` just needs to be a regular Java class. It doesn't need to inherit from anything. Remove also the lifecycle methods like `onCreate()`.

Now you will have a problem with the toast, because you need a context for that and `AgAppHelperMethods` isn't a Context. To solve that you can add `Context` as a parameter to `AgAppXMLParser()` like this:

```
public String[][] AgAppXMLParser(Context context, String parUrl) {
     ...
     // Now you can use "context" to create your toast.
}
```

When you call `AgAppXMLParser()` from `AgAppMenu` just pass "this" as the context parameter.

Comment: what i used on toas mesage   Toast.makeText(context

or Toast.makeText(context.getApplicationContext()

Comment: I've updated my profile description to include my email address. You can look there.